# IllegalStateException in Roboelectric with SupportFragmentTestUtil.startVisibleFragment(myFragment)

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, robolectric

I'm setting up this class for testing my fragment:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyFragmentTest {

    MyFragment myFragment;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        myFragment = (MyFragment)FmyFragment.instantiate(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), MyFragment.class.getName());
        SupportFragmentTestUtil.startVisibleFragment(myFragment);
    }

}
```

But the line

```
SupportFragmentTestUtil.startVisibleFragment(myFragment);
```

is throwing the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
```

Did I miss something in my setup? I've tried many things and this is the closest I've been to starting my fragment with roboelectric.

If you need more info, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with a Glide Bug when using roboelectric.